# How to make a div move with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

*New to javascript* I've seen many different tutorials on how to move divs, but for some reason, it never works, here's what I've seen so far

```
let dodger = document.querySelector('dodger');
let moveBy = 10;
windows.addEventListener('load',() =>{
    dodger.style.position = 'absolue';
    dodger.style.left = 0;
    dodger.style.top = 0;
} )
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            dodger.style.left = parseInt(dodger.style.left) - moveBy + 'px';
            break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            dodger.style.left = parseInt(dodger.style.left) + moveBy + 'px';
            
            break;
        case 'ArrowUp':
            dodger.style.top = parseInt(dodger.style.top) - moveBy + 'px';
            break;
        case 'ArrowDown':
            dodger.style.top = parseInt(dodger.style.top) + moveBy + 'px';
            break;
    }
});
```

dodger being a black square 100 x 100 px

Comment: You misspelled `"absolute"` in setting the position.

Comment: @Mordred fixed, it wasn't that

Comment: `querySelector` requires a _CSS selector_ and "dodger" isn't one. Either add an id or a class to your element. And then either `document.querySelector('#dodger')` or `document.querySelector('.dodger')`.

Comment: Do you actually have a `dodger` element?

Comment: `windows` should be `window`.

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use `parseFloat`, not `parseInt`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I realized I was using Safari so the debugger wouldn't work

Comment: You might want to show what your HTML looks like. I got it to work just fine after fixing the typos in your code.

Comment: Since you have an `id="dodger"` then your querySelector needs to be: `document.querySelector('#dodger');`

Comment: dodger.style is null, not sure why

Comment: @Paige `dodger.style` can’t be `null`. [`HTMLElement.prototype.style`](//drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-elementcssinlinestyle-mixin) is not nullable. You probably mean `dodger` is `null`, which explains the error below. Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: Please don't edit your question with information provided in the comments as it then makes those comments redundant, and the question confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can get the HTML element by passing the CSS selector, If it is an `id` then you have prefix it with `#`, if class then prefix it with `.`.

```
let dodger = document.querySelector('#dodger');
```

**2)** You can get `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` from [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and move it

```js
let dodger = document.querySelector('#dodger');
let moveBy = 10;

window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const styles = getComputedStyle(dodger);
  switch (e.key) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      dodger.style.left = parseInt(styles.left) - moveBy + 'px';
      break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
      dodger.style.left = parseInt(styles.left) + moveBy + 'px';

      break;
    case 'ArrowUp':
      dodger.style.top = parseInt(styles.top) - moveBy + 'px';
      break;
    case 'ArrowDown':
      dodger.style.top = parseInt(styles.top) + moveBy + 'px';
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
#dodger {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="dodger"></div>
```

Comment: "Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'", perhaps it's my browser

Comment: then you are not passing the `#dodger` element in the `getComputedStyle` Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
const dodger = document.querySelector('#dodger');
const move = {
    ArrowLeft: {left: -1, top: 0},
    ArrowRight: {left: 1, top: 0},
    ArrowUp: {left: 0, top: -1},
    ArrowDown: {left: 0, top: 1},
  };
  const coords = dodger.getBoundingClientRect();
  const moveBy = 100;
  dodger.style.left = (move[e.key].left * moveBy) + coords.left;
  dodger.style.top = (move[e.key].top * moveBy) + coords.top;
});
```